# Изменение изображения без сохранения на хост

Tags: php

Здраствуйте, возможно ли изменить изображение на php, после чего сразу же показать его при помощи `<img>` без сохранение на хост. Например: есть изображение 300x300, я хочу уменьшить его до 100x100 и сразу же после изменения показать в `<img>` без загрузки на хостинг, или локальный сервер. Если есть такая возможность, напишите пожайлуста!

Comment: такая возможность есть, как минимум можно сохранить в "php://stdout"

Answer (score 0):

Ну если вы делаете через форму, то тут так и так будет загрузка в **/tmp**. Если так, то вот есть код наложения водяного знака, в котором используются нужные методы:

```php
function watermark($sourceImagePath)
{
    // Загрузка штампа и фото, для которого применяется водяной знак (называется штамп или печать)
    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceImagePath);

    $stamp_new = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($stamp)/2 ,imagesy($stamp)/2);
    imagealphablending($stamp_new, false);
    imagesavealpha($stamp_new, true);
    imagecopyresampled($stamp_new, $stamp, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp)/2, imagesy($stamp)/2, imagesx($stamp),imagesy($stamp));

    // Установка полей для штампа и получение высоты/ширины штампа
    $marge_right = 10;
    $marge_bottom = 10;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp_new);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp_new);

    // Копирование изображения штампа на фотографию с помощью смещения края
    // и ширины фотографии для расчёта позиционирования штампа.
    imagecopy($im, $stamp_new, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, $sx, $sy);

    imagepng($im, $sourceImagePath);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Также можно использовать captcha:

```php
<?php
session_start();
$captcha_num = rand(1000, 9999);
$_SESSION['code'] = $captcha_num;
 
// Тип содержимого
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Создание изображения
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 30);

// Создание цветов
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// Замена пути к шрифту на пользовательский
$font = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Anonymous.ttf';

// Текст
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 15, 25, $black, $font, $captcha_num);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Подключается captcha так:  `<img src="captcha.php" /><input type="text" name="captcha" />`.

Хотя ваша задача больше похожа на [типичный редактор на javascript](https://imagekit.io/blog/how-to-resize-image-in-javascript/)